# How to get Url of the WebView using WebResourceRequest in Java?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, webview

I have these codes:

```
   public class MyAppWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
            //want url of the webview in here
        }
```

I just want to know, how can I obtain the Url of the webView to override the Url loading. The `shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)` method is depreceated in API21.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading (WebView view, String url)` deprecated in API 24, `boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading (WebView view, WebResourceRequest request)` added in API level 24

```
        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
            if(Uri.parse(request.getUrl().toString()).getHost().endsWith("google.com")) {
                //The host application wants to leave the current WebView and handle the url itself. 
                return true;
            }

            if(Uri.parse(request.getUrl().toString()).getHost().endsWith("yandex.com")) {                    
                //The current WebView handles the url. 
                return false;
            }               

            if(Uri.parse(request.getUrl().toString()).getScheme().equals("file")) {
                //The current WebView handles the url. 
                return false;
            }

            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(request.getUrl().toString()));
            view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        }
```

Answer (score 10):

in **\Android\sdk\sources\android-25\android\webkit\WebViewClient.java**, you can see this code.

So short answer to your question is:
     `request.getUrl().toString()`

Check sources on [GrepCode](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.1_r1/android/webkit/WebViewClient.java#122).

Comment: What if I use lower API version than 25

Answer (score 1):

```
private String cUrl = "";

cUrl = webView.getUrl();
```

Then you can use it wherever you want.